# Angular - series of promises - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have some service that uploads a file to my server, then my server converts the file.  I use this service like this:

```
uploadService.uploadFileWaitForConversion(fileToUpload).then(
    function(fileid) {
        console.log("Upload success");
        console.log(fileid);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("error uploading");
    );
);
```

Service code:

```
// Checks the progress of the conversion.  Success means it's done.  409 means it's still converting
function checkFileStatus(uuid, attempts) {
    return $http.get('/api/upload/' + uuid, {
    }).then(
        function (response) {
            console.log("File been converted and file uuid returned");
            return response.data;
        },
        function (error) {  // API returns 409 if it's still being processed
            console.log(attempts);
            if (error.status === 409) {
                attempts--;
                if (attempts > 0) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        checkFileStatus(uuid, attempts)
                    }, 2000);
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    );
}

function uploadFileWaitForConversion(fileToUpload) {
    return $upload.upload({
        url: '/api/upload',
        file: fileToUpload
    }).then(
        function (response) {
            var fileID = response.data.file;
            console.log("File uploaded, now let's convert");
            return checkFileStatus(fileID, 5).then(
                function() {
                    console.log("Conversion done!");
                    return fileID;
                },
                function() {
                    return 0;
                }
            );
        },
        function (error) {
            return 0;
        }
    );
}
```

I'm expecting this to print:

- File uploaded, now let's convert
- 5
- 4
- 3 // conversion is done now
- File has been converted and file uuid returned
- Conversion done
- Upload success

Instead, this prints:

- File uploaded, now let's convert
- 5
- Conversion done
- Upload success
- 4
- 3 // conversion is done

Comment: without reading the whole code, you're missing a `return` before your `$timeout` as well as a `return` for the promise inside it.

Comment: Just read the code, you're missing a two returns - this is a common problem with promises - we've been debating it - if you have any nice ideas for how $q or any promise library could make finding these bugs easier in the future please let us know.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Are you a part of the Angular team?

Comment: @Shomz Angular is an open source project - I happened to discuss promise strategies with the people in the core team once or twice and may have a pull request in... this sort of thing though it something anyone can contribute in. I'm also involved in other promise related projects and we've discussed this particular issue previously in the #promises IRC channel. If you're looking to help either in angular or with promise libraries or otherwise contributors are always in short supply.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Cool! I don't think I'm *that* good with either of the two, but thank you very much both for the invitation and the explanation.